# Implement the general update pattern for an svg path

Tags: angularjs, d3.js

I have a custom chart that is loaded with some initial values on page load. When an event happens, I update the chart with some indicative arrows that show some trend. The d3 part resides inside an angular directive that gets its updated data when there is a change to the dataset from various parts of the page. What I have currently seems to work, but few path elements are not showing up. I wonder if I messed up something in the general update pattern

A snippet of the part where I have the general update pattern

```
ngApp.directive("customChart", function ($window) {
    return {
        restrict : "A",
        template : "<svg width='320' height='200'></svg>",
        scope : {
            data : "=chartData"
        },
        link : function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.line = {
                /*line function*/
            };
            scope.setChartDimensions = function () {
                // . . .
            }
            scope.render = function (dataset) {
                aData = dataset.arrows ? dataset.arrows : undefined;
                // . . . 
                if (arrowData) {
                    // . . . 
                    var path = svg
                        .selectAll("path")
                        .data(pathCoordinates, function (d) {
                            return d;
                        });

                    path.enter()
                    .append("path")
                    .attr("d", function (d) {
                        return scope.line(d) + "Z";
                    })
                    .attr("class", "enter");

                    path.exit().remove();
                }
            }
            scope.$watchCollection('data', function (newValue, oldValue) {
                scope.render(newValue);
            });
            scope.setChartDimensions();
        }
    }
}
```

When an event happens some of the arrow data is not being recognized as new or something and those arrows are not being rendered despite that data being available at the time.

Fiddle for the entire code: https://jsfiddle.net/animeshb/tbpnx0xd

Comment: Updated fiddle link